# Object ArrayList For-Loop Error

Tags: java, inheritance, arraylist, tostring

I have an Object ArrayList and I need to use the **toString()** method of the *Motor* object, which is a parameter of the *Vehicle* object. My vehicle objects are in an ArrayList which is iterated through with a for-loop (I know a foreach loop would be easier, but this is part of the assignment)

Here is the code for the loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < VehicleList.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println();
    String info = VehicleList.get(i).toString();
    Motor m = VehicleList.get(i).motor;
    String motorInfo = m.toString();
    System.out.println(info);
    System.out.println(m);
    }
```

There is an error that says "***motor cannot be resolved or is not a field***".

All of the classes should allow this to work, unless of course there is a simple mistake I am missing.

Here is the Motor class:

```
 public class Motor {
    protected String name;
    protected int cylinders;
    protected int bhp;
    protected double displacement;

    public Motor(String name, int cylinders, int bhp, double displacement) {
        this.name = name;
        this.cylinders = cylinders;
        this.bhp = bhp;
        this.displacement = displacement;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Motor name= " + name + ", cylinders= " + cylinders + ", bhp= 
     " + bhp + ", displacement= " + displacement;
    }
}
```

Motors and Vehicles are intitialized here (In the TestVehicle class):

```
        //Motors
        Motor EcoBoost = new Motor("EcoBoost", 6, 310, 2.3);
        Motor Hemi = new Motor("Hemi", 8, 707, 5.7);
        Motor P90D = new Motor("P90D", 0, 762, 0.0);

        //Vehicles
        Vehicle v0 = new PassCar("Ford", "Mustang", 2016, 44500.0, 5, true, EcoBoost);
        Vehicle v1 = new PassCar("Tesla", "Model S", 2016, 121000.0, 2, true, P90D);
        Vehicle v2= new Truck("Dodge", "Ram", 2016, 46000.0, "pickup", 1500, Hemi);
```

*PassCar* and *Truck* are inherited classes of Vehicle with a few more attributes. I can post the PassCar or Truck class if needed but I do not think that is where the problem is arising from. I believe it is coming from the For-Loop, specifically the line ***Motor m = VehicleList.get(i).motor;*** but I am not sure of how to fix it.

Vehicle Class:

```
public class Vehicle {
protected String make;
protected String model;
protected int year;
protected double price;

public Vehicle(String make, String model, int year, double price) {
    this.make = make;
    this.model = model;
    this.year = year;
    this.price = price;
}


public void description() {
    System.out.println("Description");
}

public String toString() {
    return "make= " + make + ", model= " + model + ", year= " + year + 
  ", price= " + price;
 }

}
```

EDIT: There cannot be any Getters or Setters as per the assignment requirements, and it must be an ArrayList, not a regular List. When I switch  to  I get the error "Type mismatch: cannot convert from ArrayList to ArrayList

Here is an image of the classes:
[image]

Comment: Does the `Vehicle` class have a field called `motor`?

Comment: Show the declaration of `VehicleList`.

Comment: Please post `Vehicle` class.

Comment: create variable `motor` in class `Vehicle`

Comment: @shmosel ....... ArrayList<Object> VehicleList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(vehicles)); It was created from an Object Array of the three vehicles

Comment: PassCar and Truck, both have that variable in it @Vicky Thakor, and in my assignment I am not supposed to use it in the Vehicle class

Comment: @Matthew that's a list of `Object`. Change it to `List<Vehicle>`.

Comment: Don't post code in the comments; [edit] your question if you have something to add.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> ArrayList<Object> VehicleList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(vehicles));
> ```

`VehicleList` is declared to contain instances of `Object`, so the compiler will only let you access methods and fields it knows exist on all instances of `Object`.

Change it to `ArrayList<Vehicle>`.

Comment: Part of the project requirements is that I cannot use getters or setters. Also, it cannot be a List, it must be an ArrayList. When I switch <Object> to <Vehicle> I get the error "Type mismatch: cannot convert from ArrayList<Object> to ArrayList <Vehicle>

Comment: @Matthew then presumably `vehicles` is an `Object[]`. Change that to a `Vehicle[]`.

Answer (score 0):

Create an interface `IMotor` which is used by `Vehicle` class and Implemented in `PassCar` and other implementation of vehicle.

**IMotor.java**

```
public interface IMotor {
    public Motor getMotor();
}
```

**Motor.java**

```
public class Motor {
    protected String name;
    protected int cylinders;
    protected int bhp;
    protected double displacement;

    public Motor(String name, int cylinders, int bhp, double displacement) {
        this.name = name;
        this.cylinders = cylinders;
        this.bhp = bhp;
        this.displacement = displacement;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Motor name= " + name + ", cylinders= " + cylinders + ", bhp=" + bhp + ", displacement= " + displacement;
    }
}
```

**Vehicle.java**

```
public abstract class Vehicle implements IMotor{
    protected String make;
    protected String model;
    protected int year;
    protected double price;

    public Vehicle(String make, String model, int year, double price) {
        this.make = make;
        this.model = model;
        this.year = year;
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "make= " + make + ", model= " + model + ", year= " + year + 
      ", price= " + price;
     }
}
```

**PassCar**

```
public class PassCar extends Vehicle{

    protected Motor motor;

    public PassCar(String make, String model, int year, double price, Motor motor) {
        super(make, model, year, price);
        this.motor = motor;
    }

    public Motor getMotor() {
        return motor;
    }
}
```

**Test.java**

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Motor EcoBoost = new Motor("EcoBoost", 6, 310, 2.3);
        Vehicle v0 = new PassCar("Ford", "Mustang", 2016, 44500.0, EcoBoost);

        List<Vehicle> vehicles = Arrays.asList(v0);
        System.out.println(vehicles.get(0).getMotor());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, mind the naming convention.  Variables should be named in `camcelCase` e.g. vehicleList`instead of`VehicleList`

> I have an Object ArrayList

I believe you mean declaration of `vehicleList` looks like `ArrayList<Object> vehicleList`

Then behavior is expected because compiler only knows that `VehicleList.get(i)` is going to return you an `Object` reference.  It can be a `Vehicle`, but it can also be anything else.  So it won't allow you to access the `motor` field, as there is simply no such field in `Object`.

Change your declaration to something like `List<Vehicle> vehicleList`

---

However, as mentioned in other answer, it is not a good idea to access the field directly because of various reason.  A slightly less evil way is to have getter of `motor`.  (A better way is to provide meaningful behaviors instead of providing access to internal data)

Comment: It cannot be a List, it must be an ArrayList. When I switch <Object> to <Vehicle> I get the error "Type mismatch: cannot convert from ArrayList<Object> to ArrayList <Vehicle>

Comment: @MatthewThibodeau What you need is to get more basic knowledge on Java, so you know what is the problem and solution of such type mismatch.  Of course you can always explicitly cast it as `((Vechicle) (VehicleList.get(i))).motor;` but it is almost never a proper way to fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `motor` is not a member of the `Vehicle` class, but you are trying to access it through an expression of type `Vehicle` - namely `vehicleList.get(i)`.  This  is forbidden, because the compiler has no way of knowing that every possible kind of `Vehicle` has a `motor`.  After all, what would happen if you added a `Bicycle` class?

To make this work,  you should remove `motor` from the `Truck` and `PassCar` classes, and add it to the `Vehicle` class.  That way, `vehicleList.get(i).motor` would actually make sense, since the `Vehicle` expression would be guaranteed to refer to a `Vehicle` with a `Motor`.

It would also be recommended to use a getter for the `motor` field - that is, have `motor` as a `private` field of the `Vehicle` class, and write a method `getMotor()` to return it.  You could then write `vehicleList.get(i).getMotor()` to get the `Motor` object associated with one `Vehicle` in the list.

Answer (score -2):

Thanks to the help of all of your comments and my Java textbook, I managed to piece it together. Here is how I got it to work:

```
for (int i = 0; i < vehicleList.size(); i++) {
    String motorInfo = "";
    String info = "";
    System.out.println();
    if (vehicleList.get(i) instanceof PassCar) {
        info = ((PassCar)vehicleList.get(i)).toString();
        **motorInfo = ((PassCar)vehicleList.get(i)).motor.toString();**

    }
    else if(vehicleList.get(i) instanceof Truck) {
        info = ((Truck)vehicleList.get(i)).toString();
        **motorInfo = ((Truck)vehicleList.get(i)).motor.toString();**
    }
```

Basically I had to use a polymorphic call and check if it was an instance of a PassCar or Truck.
And as for the Array and ArrayList used during the Class, I edited them like this:

```
Vehicle [] vehicles = new Vehicle [3]; 
vehicles[0] = v0;
vehicles[1] = v1;
vehicles[2] = v2;

showVehicle(vehicles);

ArrayList<Vehicle> vehicleList = new ArrayList<Vehicle>(Arrays.asList(vehicles));
System.out.println();
System.out.println("Output from ArrayList in main: ");
```

Thank you for the help everyone!

Comment: To be honest it would be better to have the `Motor` as part of the `Vehicle` then you would not need the above ugly code.  With both `Truck` and `PassCar` they both have an engine.  If you wanted to create a Vehicle without a `Motor` (Bicycle) then maybe create a non-engine `Motor`

Comment: I understand completely. Normally I would have done it like that but the assignment required me to do it this way. Thanks for your feedback

Comment: You don't need the casts before the calls to `toString`.  And this is a simply terrible way of solving this problem.

Comment: There are numerous ways to solve a problem, so keep an open mind. Maybe next time read a little further where I explicitly state why I can't do it another way. @DawoodibnKareem